# Join the columns for dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following dataframe with date information:

```
      import numpy as np
      import pandas as pd

      df_Date = pd.DataFrame({'Day' : ['2', '19', '22', '15', '16'], 
                              'Month' : ['2', '8', '1', '11', '10'], 
                              'Year' : ['2010', '2010', '2010', '2010', '2010'], 
                              'Hour' : ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
                              'Minute' : ['59', '55', '33', '45', '5'],
                              'Second' : ['16', '17', '18', '19', '20']                       
                             })
```

I would like to generate, just one column, containing the complete date (Day, Month, Year, Hour, Minute and Secund).

I tried to implement the following code:

```
     df_Date['Day'] = df_Date['Day'].astype(int)
     df_Date['Month'] = df_Date['Month'].astype(int)
     df_Date['Year'] = df_Date['Year'].astype(int)

     df_Date['New_Column_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_Date.Year*10000 + df_Date.Month*100 + 
                                                 df_Date.Day, format='%Y%m%d')
```

This code is working. However, it is not complete, the hours minutes and second are missing.

My exit is like this:

```
        Day   Month     Year    Hour    Minute  Second  New_Column_Date
         2      2       2010    1         59    16          2010-02-02
         19     8       2010    2         55    17          2010-08-19
         22     1       2010    3         33    18          2010-01-22
         15     11      2010    4         45    19          2010-11-15
         16     10      2010    5          5    20          2010-10-16
```

I would like the output to be:

```
        Day   Month     Year    Hour    Minute  Second  New_Column_Date
         2      2       2010    1         59    16          2010-02-02 01:59:16
         19     8       2010    2         55    17          2010-08-19 02:55:17
         22     1       2010    3         33    18          2010-01-22 03:33:18
         15     11      2010    4         45    19          2010-11-15 04:45:19
         16     10      2010    5          5    20          2010-10-16 05:05:20
```

Comment: In this dataframe I have only date columns. But what if the dataframe contains other columns? what should I do?

Comment: Just do `df['New Col'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Second']])`

Comment: Perfect! Tkank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine multiple columns in a Data Frame to Pandas datetime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718863/how-to-combine-multiple-columns-in-a-data-frame-to-pandas-datetime-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your headers are named as shown in your post, you can delegate all the heavy lifting to `pd.to_datetime`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Second']])

0   2010-02-02 01:59:16
1   2010-08-19 02:55:17
2   2010-01-22 03:33:18
3   2010-11-15 04:45:19
4   2010-10-16 05:05:20
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The precondition is that you name your columns "Year", "Month", "Day", ... etc as shown above. The order of the columns isn't even that important. The names are extremely important.