# Pandas date parsing from CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime, date-parsing

I have one csv file:

```
year;month;day;hour;min;sec;temperature
2022;10;27;13;36;42;5.835
2022;10;27;14;36;42;6.435
2022;10;27;15;36;42;6.335
2022;10;27;16;36;42;6.435
```

And I would like to plot a simple graph from it. I am not able to combine separate datetime parts. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

def parser(year, month, day, hour, minute, second):
    return pd.to_datetime(day + '.' + month + '.' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second

df = pd.read_csv('temp_data.csv',sep=';',parse_dates={'datetime':['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'min', 'sec']}, date_parser=parser,index_col=0)

time = df['datetime'].values
temp = df['temperature'].values

plt.plot(time, temp)
```

Comment: Note that `time = df['datetime'].values"` can't work as `datetime` is the index and not a column.

Comment: See also [How to combine multiple columns in a Data Frame to Pandas datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49718863/10197418)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

> I would like the x-axis date format to be: 27.10.22

You have to handle manually formatting.

Simply use [`df.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# df = pd.read_csv(...)

ax = df.plot()
loc = mdates.DayLocator()
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d.%m.%y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I also get the graph but unfortunately cannot get the x-axis dates right. Pleas see the picture: [Link](https://i.ibb.co/4sCbYrx/py.png)

Comment: I would like the x-axis date format to be: 27.10.22

Comment: Thank you! The x-axis format is right, but the numbers are wrong. I think the problem is in function: parse_dates. Does Pandas know, that for example "second" means it is part on time... Here is picture: [Link](https://ibb.co/hDxzCkj)

Comment: Also tried: ax = df.plot(x='datetime',y='tempc')

Comment: If I write in console: df.info(), it says that datetime type is "object" but should be "datetime[ns]"

Comment: I was able to solve it by this line: df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month','day','hour','minute','second']]
                   .astype(str).apply(' '.join, 1), format='%Y %m %d %H %M %S')

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make your code work on my pc using python 3.11

```py
df = pd.read_csv(
    "temp_data.csv",
    sep=";",
    parse_dates={"datetime": ["year", "month", "day", "hour", "min", "sec"]},
    date_parser=parser,
    # index_col=0, this line was causing the problem
)
```

My plot wouldn't show as well, so I had to do this too:

```py
plt.plot(time, temp)
plt.show(block=True)
```