# pandas add datetime column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe where year, month, day, hour is split into separate columns:

```
df.head()
    Year   Month   Day  Hour
0   2020   1       1    0
1   2020   1       1    1
2   2020   1       1    2
   ...
```

I'd like to add a proper datetime column to the dataframe so I end up with something along these lines:

```
df.head()
    Year   Month   Day  Hour datetime
0   2020   1       1    0    2020-01-01T00:00
1   2020   1       1    1    2020-01-01T01:00
2   2020   1       1    2    2020-01-01T02:00
   ...
```

I could add a loop that processes one row at a time, but that's not panda-esque.
Here are three things that don't work (not that I expected any of them to do so):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(datetime.datetime(df['Year'], df['Month'], df['Day'], df['Hour']))
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'], df['Month'], df['Day'], df['Hour'])
df['datetime'] = pd.datetime(df['Year'], df['Month'], df['Day'], df['Hour'])
```

Comment: @BallpointBen Yes, but I like this answer better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26142793/558639.  voting to close my question...

Comment: This works like you expected the last 3 examples to: df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime({"year": df['Year'], "month": df['Month'], "day": df['Day'], "hour": df['Hour']})