# Python - Parse separate datetime colums to one

Tags: python, parsing, datetime

I am trying to parse 6 datetime columns to one withon a .dat-file. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301589/parsing-dd-mm-yy-hh-mm-ss-columns-from-txt-file-using-pythons-pandas) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193835/parse-dates-when-year-month-day-and-hour-are-in-separate-columns-using-pandas-in) but I remain to get errors. My file looks like this:

```
YYYY MM DD HH MM SS Julday a b c d
Lat                        35...
Lon                        -120...
Elev                       680
2015 10 09 00 00 30 235.34 3 4 2 6
...
```

I have about 400 rows. I want the 6 datetime columns to be in the usual way like 2013-10-09 00:00:30.

I hve tried this for example:

```
dat-file = pd.read_csv('C:/.../myfile.dat', header=4, sep='\s+\s', parse_dates=[[0]])
```

But I get the error message:

```
ValueError: New date column already in dict 2013 10 20 00 47 30
```

I am new to python and have not used pandas yet. Probably there is a problem reading a .dat-file with `pd.read_csv`? Thanks!

Comment: Hi. You have two errors here:  
1. when the `header` argument in `read_csv` is an integer, say `n`, it takes the `n`th row as the header. So in your case, it would take the fourth row as the header, which is not the case.  2. The correct value for the `parse_dates` argument is `[range(6)]`, which makes pandas combine the first six columns into a single datetime column.

Comment: Is non aligning row repeats after first three?

Comment: thank you very much @Jaidev Deshpande. I now tried `import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/.../myfile.dat', header=1, sep='\s+\s', parse_dates=([range(6)])` but I don't get any response, nothing happens. The very first row is my header row, I do not need the second, third and fourth row, so I need to skip those.

Comment: @WoodChopper: sorry, what do you mean? I edited my question a little bit. I do not need the second, third and fourth row.

Comment: Header is `YYYY MM DD HH MM SS Julday a b c d` aligning row is `2015 10 09 00 00 30 235.34 3 4 2 6` right?

Comment: @WoodChopper: yes, header is `YYYY...` and the first row needed is `2015 ...`

Comment: if `header=4` your column index in dataframe will became `2015 10 09 00 00 30 235.34 3 4 2 6`.

Comment: Look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193835/parse-dates-when-year-month-day-and-hour-are-in-separate-columns-using-pandas-in?lq=1

Comment: @WoodChopper: yes, this is exactly what the column index is when using that code. I have tried it with `header=1`, because the first row actually is the needed header, but I do not get anything. No error message and nothing happens. I do not know neither what the separator `\s+\s` means, maybe there is something wring as well?

Comment: okay I have simply deleted the 3 rows not needed. when I am doing `import pandas as pd df = pd.read_csv('C:/.../myfile.dat', header=1, sep='\s+\s', parse_dates=([range(6)])` as suggested, now I get the error message `ValueError: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] is not in list
`

Comment: @WoodChopper: I have already tried the suggested answer with: `df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, index_col='datetime', 
                 parse_dates={'datetime': [0,1,2,3,4,5]}, 
                 date_parser=lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d %H %M %S'))
` which does not work. I get the error: `IOError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <type 'numpy.ndarray'> type
`